# Haskell Https Get Proxy Request

Tags: http, haskell, proxy, get

I have a working `getRequest` via a `Proxy` :

```
main = do
  rsp <- browse $ do
    setProxy . fromJust $ parseProxy "128.199.232.117:3128"
    request $ getRequest "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yj_wyw6Xrq4"
  print $ rspBody <$> rsp
```

But it's `htpps` and so basically I get an Exception. But I foud out [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html) that it can also work with `htpps` :

```
import Network.Connection (TLSSettings (..))
import Network.HTTP.Conduit

main :: IO ()
main = do
    request <- parseUrl "https://github.com/"
    let settings = mkManagerSettings (TLSSettingsSimple True False False) Nothing
    manager <- newManager settings
    res <- httpLbs request manager
    print res
```

But I have no idea how to integrate this into my Proxy getRequest Code?

Could someone show me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using [HTTP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.22/docs/Network-Browser.html#v:browse) package it the first snippet and [http-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:mkManagerSettings) in the second one.

Unfortunately `HTTP` doesn't support `https`, so your can't "integrate" the second snippet into the first one. But `http-conduit` supports proxies, so you can use [addProxy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.8/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v:addProxy) function to set proxy host and port (not tested):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadesStrings #-}
...
request <- do
  req <- parseUrl "https://github.com/"
  return $ addProxy "128.199.232.117" 3128 req
...
```

Comment: doesnt work @Yuras : `Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
                with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the first argument of ‘addProxy’, namely ‘"128.199.232.117"’`

Comment: @MartinFischer are you sure you added the `OverloadedStrings` pragma?